# python string to function: globals() vs sys.module vs dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, module, global-variables, getattr

I want to know what is the best way to map the string to a function.
so far I know I can use:

1. globals()[func_string]
2. sys.modules[__name__]
3. funcs_dictionary["func_string" : func]

Here is the code:

```
    >>> def foo(arg):
    ...     print "I'm foo: %s" % arg
    ... 
    >>> def bar(arg):
    ...     print "I'm bar: %s" % arg
    ... 
    >>> 
    >>> foo
    <function foo at 0xb742c7d4>
    >>> bar
    <function bar at 0xb742c80c>
    >>>
```

globals()[func_string]:

```
    >>> def exec_funcs_globals(funcs_string):
    ...     for func_string in funcs_string:
    ...         func = globals()[func_string]
    ...         func("from globals() %s" % func)
    ... 
    >>> exec_funcs_globals(["foo", "bar"])
    I'm foo: from globals() <function foo at 0xb742c7d4>
    I'm bar: from globals() <function bar at 0xb742c80c>
    >>>
```

sys.modules[__name__]:

```
    >>> import sys
    >>> 
    >>> def exec_funcs_thismodule(funcs_string):
    ...     thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
    ...     for func_string in funcs_string:
    ...         func = getattr(thismodule, func_string)
    ...         func("from thismodule %s" % func)
    ... 
    >>> exec_funcs_thismodule(["foo", "bar"])
    I'm foo: from thismodule <function foo at 0xb742c7d4>
    I'm bar: from thismodule <function bar at 0xb742c80c>
    >>>
```

funcs_dictionary["func_string" : func]:

```
    >>> funcs = {
    ...     "foo" : foo,
    ...     "bar" : bar
    ... }
    >>> 
    >>> def exec_funcs_dict(funcs_string):
    ...     for func_string in funcs_string:
    ...         func = funcs[func_string]
    ...         func("from thismodule %s" % func)
    ... 
    >>> exec_funcs_dict(["foo", "bar"])
    I'm foo: from thismodule <function foo at 0xb742c7d4>
    I'm bar: from thismodule <function bar at 0xb742c80c>
```

Originally I was worry about the sys.modules[__name__] will reload the modules and hurt the performance. But the code above seem to show that the function pointers are the same, so I guess I don't have to worry about it?

What is the best use case for the option 1, 2, 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *globals()* is the normal way to access (and store) variables you want to access globally.

Otherwise, the usual choice is to implement a dispatch dictionary (like your option 3).

I've not seen the *sys.modules* approach used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only a novice Python coder (< 6 months) but to answer your question directly, it actually seems to me that **sys.modules** is the "best" solution if you're looking for the most flexible.  Here's why:

1. Creating a **new dictionary** manually seems like wasted effort when the data already exists and can be accessed using both the **globals()** and **sys.modules** approaches.
2. The **globals()** and **sys.modules** approaches also allow you to automatically and dynamically farm (and then filter) lists of functions - useful if, like me, you were trying to automatically build GUIs/menus from all functions defined in your code.
3. A consideration with **globals()** is that if you import and call the "function farmer" from another module, you'll only get the functions of the "function farmer" module itself, not the parent module.  [There might be a solution for this... I've posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971629/getting-function-objects-from-globals-and-locals-across-different-modules) and will update this response if I hear anything useful back.]
4. Using **sys.modules** on the other hand, you can call the "function farmer" and get the functions of the '__ main __' module.