# Getting function objects from globals() and locals() across different modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, python-module, global-scope

**Question:** Is there a way to use `globals()` or `locals()` but from a different (imported) module rather than `"__main__"`, without having to then grind through the results to find, for example, just the function objects?

**What I've tried so far:** *(showing different shades of ignorance and confusion!)*

`module2.globals`
`module2.globals()`
`"module2".globals`
`"module2".globals()`
`globals(module2)`
`globals().module2`
`globals().module2()`
`__name__.globals`
`__name__.globals()`
`"__main__".globals()`
`"__main__".globals`

My best prospects were `module2.__dict__` and `module2.__dict__.keys()` - but I couldn't see how I'd filter the results without great deviousness...

**Background:** (and why I'm not looking for a `sys.modules()` answer, thanks)

My original goal was to "farm" a list of function objects from any new module I created and after some filtering, use that list to procedurally generate a menu or GUI.  I came up with the following approach using `sys.modules` as a first step in "function farming" so I have a solution, just not a full understanding - hence my long-winded question.

```
# module1

import sys

def get_functions_A(module = "__main__"):
    values1 = sys.modules[module].__dict__.values()
    print([x for x in values1 if str(type(x))=="<class 'function'>"])
```

I got identical results using `globals()` and `values()` below, which looked promising at first:

```
# module1    
...
def get_functions_B(module = "__main__"):
    values2 = list(globals().values())   
    print([x for x in values2 if str(type(x))=="<class 'function'>"])
```

I prefer this 2nd approach because it reads much less like an arcane incantation to me as a newcomer to Python.

However, when I tried putting this `globals()`-based function into a ***different*** module (my personal "go-to" library of tools and tricks) and importing it from there, I noticed it was only farming functions from its *own* module, `module2`:

```
# module2

def get_functions_B2(module="__main__"):
    values2=list(globals().values())   
    print([x for x in values2 if str(type(x))=="<class 'function'>"])
```

and then:

```
# module1

from module2 import get_functions_B2

def get_functions_B1(module = "__main__"):
    values1 = list(globals().values())   
    print([x for x in values1 if str(type(x))=="<class 'function'>"])
```

Correct output as desired from `module1` and `get_functions_B1`:

`[<function get_functions_B2 at 0x000002059594DBF8>, <function get_functions_B1 at 0x0000020593593E18>]`

Incorrect (partial) output from `module1` and import of `get_functions_B2`:

`[<function get_functions_B2 at 0x000002494CC7DBF8>]`

I now understand why this is happening ("global" actually means "module-wide"), and replied to a related Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220620/python-string-to-function-globals-vs-sys-module-vs-dictionary/49970321#49970321) but would still like to know if I'm missing an elegant or obvious way of using `globals()` instead of `sys.modules()` please.

This is my first question on StackOverflow so thanks for your patience & help...